# Where have I messed this up? CGI/BASH

Tags: html, bash, cgi

I am working on a final project for the semester and haven't the slightest where I have mad a mistake as the information was taken from notes.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "inside formdemo.cgi" > /www/local.FoneBookSearch.com/cgilog
read information
echo "$information" > /www/local.FoneBookSearch.com/cgilog
firstname=`echo $information | cut -d '=' -f2 | cut -d '+' -f1`
lastname=`echo $information | cut -d '=' -f2 | cut -d '+' -f2`
search=`if(grep -iw "$firstname" phonebook || grep -iw "$lastname" phonebook)
then
echo "$search"
else
echo "That person was not found. Please try again"`

#construct a webpage
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title> Fone Book Search </title></head><body>"
echo "<h1> Search Results </h1>"
echo "<center> $search </center>"
```

Im sure this is all a bit trivial to everyone, but to the likes of me it's a bit much. I will be spending time researching properly but as the semester ends today I was curious if anyone could tell me where I've gone drastically wrong?

Error Code from TextMate:

```
formdemo.cgi: command substitution: line 17: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Content-Type: text/html

<html><head><title> Fone Book Search </title></head><body>
<h1> Search Results </h1>
<center>  </center>
```

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) points to the last backtick saying `Expected 'fi' matching previously mentioned 'if'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the `if` statement with `fi` after the line:

```
echo "That person was not found. Please try again"`
```

Moreover, backticks are deprecated in 2014 and difficult to 'spot'.

The backquote (`) is used in the old-style command substitution. The foo=$(command) syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: My understanding is that entire block behind search was to be used as the input to the variable "search". The other end of the backtick starts right after search as a variable a few lines up.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something small! I agree with doing this different but was instructed to expand upon original code. I had forgotten my fi at the end. I do thank you!